# git: keep only the latest version of a specific file

Tags: git, pdf, version-control, github, binaryfiles

I keep some [LaTex course notes](https://github.com/adamatan/technion_android_crash_course_notes) in github. My colleagues don't know how to use LaTex, and asked me to put the final PDF in the repo.

Keeping binary build results in a repo is generally a bad idea, and uploading the [PDF as an extenal file](https://github.com/adamatan/technion_android_crash_course_notes/downloads) after each push isn't convenient.

Is there a way to keep only the latest version of the PDF in the repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already on github, there's a panel called "Downloads" where you can add whichever file you have. There's probably an API-call for that if you want to add it to a hook for when you're pushing. You could also probably just build + copy the pdf to your dropbox account/rsync it to a common folder/use another share-my-files-API/..

You might be better off to generate the pdf + email it to them, also triggered by a hook.

If you do end up building, adding the pdf to the repo and then updating that file a lot, the repo will grow really big since the diffs it will have to hold on to will take a lot of unnecessary space.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same question. Some years have passed, and I think the existing answers are no longer quite optimal. If I'm understanding correctly, github downloads are no longer a free feature -- you get this feature only if you're paying money for your github account.

Although Sergiu Dumitriu's answer is correct in pointing out the disadvantages of rewriting history in git, both the OP and I are working on solo projects, and for such a project, it's actually not that big a deal to rewrite history.

A solution that seems to work pretty well for me as of 2022 is the following. I make a Github Pages web page for my project, in a docs/ subdirectory. When I compile my latex file to a pdf, my makefile copies the pdf into that directory. The pdf file is under version control. As time goes on, the binary diffs of this pdf file massively bloat the size of my directory tree. However, I can then use git filter-repo (a third-party tool) to delete the file from my project's history. Then my makefile script copies the latest version of the file back into the docs/ subdirectory. Here's what the relevant portion of my makefile looks like:

```
forget_pdf_history:
    test -e $(BOOK).pdf || exit 1
    git commit --allow-empty -a -m "updating before erasing history of docs/$(BOOK).pdf"
    git filter-repo --path docs/$(BOOK).pdf --invert-paths
    make reconfigure_git
    cp $(BOOK).pdf docs
    git add docs/$(BOOK).pdf
    git push --force -u origin master

reconfigure_git:
    git remote add origin https://github.com/bcrowell/ransom.git
    git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:bcrowell/ransom.git
```

It's admittedly pretty ugly that I have to rebuild the configuration of git, but it does work, and it allows me to have a reasonable web site for the book without using any resources other than github.

Comment: To avoid having to reconfigure the remotes, we can use the `--partial` option.

Answer (score 3):

There's no nice and easy way to remove old versions of a file from a repository. Each commit is secure, meaning that the identifier of a commit is built using, among others, the content of each file. There are ways of [rewriting the history](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) of a git repository, but doing that completely breaks any chance of collaboration, since you're basically creating a new repository each time you rewrite the history.

An alternative is to use the [git annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) which was designed especially for this goal: managing large files in a small repository. Unfortunately, that's a pretty new feature, and it's not part of the official Git, so support for it isn't as good.